# Magento 2 Braintree declined orders not sending Payment Failed emails

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, onepage-checkout, braintree

I'm using **Braintree** as default payment method for my Magento 2.2.3 store.

Sometimes, It happens that customer cannot finish checkout as his CC gets declined, when this happens I would like to get notified on email with information like what customer experienced this problem, what did he have in cart and what was order total.

As far as I understand, Magento 2 has [this feature built-in](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-payment-failed-emails.html) but looks like it's not working properly with **Braintree payment method**. How could I fix this? I see that function **`sendPaymentFailedEmail`** is called from module checkout controller named **`SaveOrder.php`** in case of 2 errors (in 2 catch blocks), but it does not seem that Braintree error ever gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this when I manually applied [this patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11603) , I hope this will be merged soon :)